# jquery proxy passing parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-events

How can you pass a string via proxy when binding event handlers? I want to pass a data attribute that is attached to the target handler to a method of an object. Is this possible?

```js
function ReservationSchedulePicker(reservationType){

//Reservation Type Accepted Use: 'routine' || 'vacation'
this.reservationType = reservationType;

//DIV for Schedule Picker
this.schedulePickerDiv = $("#schedulePicker");

//Add Event Handler to Anchor
$(this.schedulePickerDiv).on( "click", "#addWalk", $.proxy(this.openAddWalkDialog, this));
}

}
    
ReservationSchedulePicker.prototype.openAddWalkDialog = function(event, day) {
//Trying to pass the data-day value to this function using proxy



}


     //I need the data-day value inside of openAddWalkDialog Is this possible?
     <a href="#" id="addWalk" data-day="monday">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ReservationSchedulePicker(reservationType){
        this.reservationType = reservationType;
        this.schedulePickerDiv = $("#schedulePicker");
        this.schedulePickerDiv.on( "click", "#addWalk", $.proxy(this.openAddWalkDialog, this));
    }

    ReservationSchedulePicker.prototype.openAddWalkDialog = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(this.reservationType);
    }
    $(document).on('ready',function(){
        var x = new ReservationSchedulePicker('hello world');
    });

</script>
<div id="schedulePicker">
    <a href="#" id="addWalk" data-day="monday">Hello</a>
</div>
```

**Update 1: Based additional details provided in comments**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ReservationSchedulePicker(reservationType){
        this.reservationType = reservationType;
        this.schedulePickerDiv = $("#schedulePicker");
        this.schedulePickerDiv.on( "click", "#addWalk", $.proxy(this.openAddWalkDialog, this, $("#addWalk").attr('data-day') ));
    }



    ReservationSchedulePicker.prototype.openAddWalkDialog = function(attr, event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(this.reservationType + '=>'+ attr);
    }
    $(document).on('ready',function(){
        var x = new ReservationSchedulePicker('hello world');
    });

</script>
<div id="schedulePicker">
    <a href="#" id="addWalk" data-day="monday">Hello</a>
</div>
```

**Update 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ReservationSchedulePicker(reservationType){
        this.reservationType = reservationType;
        this.schedulePickerDiv = $("#schedulePicker");
        this.schedulePickerDiv.on( "click", "#addWalk", $.proxy(this.openAddWalkDialog, this ));
    }



    ReservationSchedulePicker.prototype.openAddWalkDialog = function( event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        alert(this.reservationType + '=>'+ ($(event.target).data('day'))) ;
    }
    $(document).on('ready',function(){
        var x = new ReservationSchedulePicker('hello world');
    });

</script>
<div id="schedulePicker">
    <a href="#" id="addWalk" data-day="monday">Hello</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything is working fine.. when the link is clicked the alert fires off from openAddWalkDialog() just like it is suppose to.

What I need now is to send the #addWalk link data-day attribute to the openAddWalkDialog() function somehow. I believe I would need to pass it as a parameter on the proxy function, I'm just unsure of how to do that :/

Comment: @JustinHarris I just provided an updated version based on those last comments.

Comment: There are 7 different links with the id of #addWalk so I need to specifically get the attribute for the link that was clicked. Is this possible? Right now all the links clicked return the same data-day using the $("#addWalk").attr('data-day')

Comment: @JustinHarris last update any new requirement will have to go to a new topic

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var that = this;

$(this.schedulePickerDiv).on("click", "#addWalk", function(e){
    that.openAddWalkDialog.call(this, e);
});

ReservationSchedulePicker.prototype.openAddWalkDialog = function(event) {
    console.log(event, $(this).data('day'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, however the data is coming back undefined. clickedElement is coming out correctly. 

My links are setup as so

    <a id="addWalk" data-day="1" href="#"></a>

Answer (score 1):

What about something like reference arguments to proxy:

```
$(this.schedulePickerDiv).on('click', '#addWalk', $.proxy(this.openAddWalkDialog, this, { foo: bar }));
```

Or on the event.data object (event.data.foo):

```
$(this.schedulePickerDiv).on('click', '#addWalk', { foo: bar }, $.proxy(this.openAddWalkDialog, this));
```