# JavaScript OOP - when parameters passed for method bind with an event

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, bind

I am trying to pass parameters to `class` method, but when I bind that method with an event then it only work once when class is initiated.

But when I try without passing a parameter then it work as usual, and act properly with event.

I cannot set parameter for `displayMessageWithParam($param)` inside class, cause it may be used by other people and I want them to pass their parameters. It work without binding to an event, but why not when I bind to an event ?

please tell me what I am doing wrong:

```
jQuery(function() {

    // create document
    Klass.site = new Klass.site();
    // need to call init manually with jQuery
    Klass.site.initialize();

});

// namespace our code
window.Klass = {};

// my class (no Class.create in JQuery so code in native JS)
Klass.site = function() {};

// add functions to the prototype
Klass.site.prototype = {
    // automatically called
    initialize: function() {
        // this works as usual
        jQuery('#field').keyup( jQuery.proxy(this.displayMessage, this));

        // but this wont work
        jQuery('#field').keyup( jQuery.proxy(this.displayMessageWithParam('chanaged'), this));
    },
    displayMessage:function(){
        console.log('chanaged');
    }
    displayMessageWithParam:function($parm){
        console.log($parm);
    }

};
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `'changed'` rather than `'chnaged'`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery proxy passing parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913427/jquery-proxy-passing-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of parentheses (e.g. `Obj.method(...)`) calls a method immediately. To refer to a method, you have to use the name without the parenthesized expression.

If you check the API documentation, `jQuery.proxy` can take additional arguments to pass as parameters.

```
jQuery('#field').keyup(jQuery.proxy(this.displayMessageWithParam, this, 'changed'));
```

There's no language support for lazy evaluation, so outside of `jQuery.proxy` you have to create and pass a callable yourself. An alternative to the above that works in general is to use an anonymous function:

```
jQuery('#field').keyup(jQuery.proxy(function () {
        this.displayMessageWithParam('changed');
    }, this));
```

Note that you can use this approach to also bind the object:

```
var self = this;
jQuery('#field').keyup(function () {
        self.displayMessageWithParam('changed');
    });
```

You could also create general purpose parameter binding function:

```
function bindParam(f, param) {
    return function () {
        var args = [].slice.apply(arguments);
        args.unshift(param);
        return f.apply(this, args);
    };
}
```

Note that this is a variation of what `jQuery.proxy` itself does. Usage:

```
... bindParam(this.displayMessageWithParam, 'changed') ...;
```

If the browser supports [`Function.bind`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5) (see also the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff841995.aspx) documentation for the implementation description/usage), you can use that instead of `jQuery.proxy` and the above.

```
jQuery('#field').keyup(this.displayMessageWithParam.bind(this, 'changed'));
```

Implementing `Function.bind` if not browser supported left as an exercise.

Also, JS doesn't support classes at the language level, so it doesn't have class and instance methods (some libraries add class-based inheritance, but that's not part of the language). It uses what's called a "prototype-based programming". If you want what might be called a "class method" in another language, define the method on the constructor, rather than on the prototype:

```
Klass.method = function () {...};
```

Unlike some other languages, this "class method" wouldn't be invoked if you try to call it directly from an instance (`(new Klass).method` is unrelated to `Klass.method`).

Comment: Thanks for help. I have defined a method in constructor, but still same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are not binding the displayMessageWithParam function but instead the value after that function is called. Use `Function.prototype.bind` to bind the arguments:

```
jQuery('#field').keyup( jQuery.proxy(this.displayMessageWithParam.bind(this,'chanaged'), this));
```

Comment: can I pass any number of parameter like: `displayMessageWithParam.bind(this, $parm1, $param2, ..)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `this.displayMessageWithParam`, `this.displayMessageWithParam('chanaged')` is not a function reference; rather it immediately executes the function and uses its return value (which is `undefined`).

However, you can instruct [`jQuery.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/#jQuery-proxy-function-context-additionalArguments) to pass in additional arguments, e.g.:

```
jQuery('#field').keyup(jQuery.proxy(this.displayMessageWithParam, this, 'changed'));
```

Or:

```
jQuery('#field').keyup(jQuery.proxy(this, 'displayMessageWithParam', 'changed'));
```

The function will then get called like:

```
this.displayMessageWithParam('changed', event)
```